# PHP using temp files in multiple PHP files?

Tags: php, file, upload

I have a PHP file that has a `$_FILES` variable in it, and I obviously have a temp file of the file uploaded saved. Problem is that what I want to do is let the user upload the image, validate that it's okay (both via 1st php file), and then allow the user to enter info about the image. From the info I can obtain the name of the image and use `move_uploaded_file()` to save the image (on the second PHP). The problem is that the file uploaded to the temp file is, well, temporary, and so I can't use it in my second PHP file. Is there any way to go around that? I can `move_uploaded_file()` in the first file but I'm looking for something easier. I still want it to be like a temp folder in the sense that the file is temporary, but I want to keep it for a couple of minutes after the execution of the first PHP file...

Thanks.

Comment: why don't they enter the info, and do the upload at the same time?

Comment: @Dagon I need to check if the image is valid (sizes and stuff) first, also I think it's more logical to upload it while they're typing stuff.

Comment: Temporary upload files are always removed when the script ends, I don't think there's a way around it. I suggest you copy it to some other location managed by your script. Use a cron job to clean up these files if they haven't been moved to the permanent locations.

Comment: then you have to move the file to your own temp dir, file moving is the same as renaming so its no great resource use. I disagree with the logic comment, this is exactly the approach i take - and for the same reason :-)

Comment: @Dagon: "file moving is the same as renaming so its no great resource use" --- as soon as you're on the same logical partition

Comment: @zerkms point taken, but it is hard not to make some assumption when answering a question, i assume you will still be alive to read this.

Comment: @Dagon: didn't actually mean to pick on, just pointed it out to not confuse further readers :-)

Comment: @zerkms i know, i agree :-) (my assumption that you will still be alive has proven to been correct ) ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first page - the one that accepts the file - will need to use `move_uploaded_file()`. You cannot escape this requirement.

However, you can use `tempnam()` to create a new temporary filename and use `move_uploaded_file()` to copy the file to that name. Then pass that second filename to the second page so it knows where it is.

The other alternative is to collapse all the input and processing into one POST, so that all the information is entered at the same time the file is uploaded. This approach has always worked for me.

Comment: Can you explain to me what you mean by "collapsing all the input/processing into one POST"?

Comment: I mean instead of separating the file upload and information entry into two (or more) forms and two (or more) POSTs, just do it all in one form and one POST.

Comment: But the thing is that I want to notify the user if his/her image is appropriate or not before rather than tell him/her AFTER he/she entered the info.

Comment: Then move the file to a new name and/or location like I suggested in the answer.